# Elasticsearch Search by popular names

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, search, lucene, elastic-stack

As many cities are known by their common/popular names like Madras is still used to search instead of chennai, same for gurgaon. I have cityindex where I have stored documents containing city info, I wan't to search for documents based on their common names. What should be the best approach for the same ?

Comment: Read about synonyms in elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms.html

Comment: Thanks this helped..!!

Comment: Glad it helped!